# Spring LDAP add new OU

Tags: java, spring-ldap

Is it possible to add new OU via spring ldap template? I am using it to add new users and groups, but I have no idea hot make it with organisational unit. Especially what attributes to put there. I am using 389DS as LDAP server and spring ldap in version 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an OU is not that different from adding new users.

You need to define the objectClass attribut (organizationalUnit) and all required attributes (ou).

The basic object classes as well as their required and optional attributes are documented in RFC4519 but should also be mentioned in the manuals of your LDAP server.